# change product per page

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am working on project , i want to change products per page based on some selection .

Like if user click price filter 0-100 i want product per page to be 10, when he selects 0,200 i want product per page to be 20 .

- How this be done i some way .
- Need help with logic how to do it .

Comment: are taking about layered navigation?

Comment: product detail page number of products per page , and yes filter from layered navigation

Comment: have use any 3-rd party module for layernavgation

Comment: no not any modules it is simple layer navigation